# How to structure a template file which might be different for groups of hosts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a template file `iptables.j2` which contains a few core rules (e.g. allowing SSH connections). However depending on the role of a node, that template will contain additional rules which cannot be managed using variables. e.g. mongo nodes will need to open port 27000 and nginx nodes ports 80 & 443 etc..

Are there examples of conditional includes of extra content into a base template that can solve my problem ?

Comment: Why not having a "lineinfile" that will update the generic iptables in your role files

Comment: I find the `lineinfile` module to be flaky as it depends on the content of the iptables file. I started using this in the past; then progressed to having separate iptables file for each role. It works fine but the duplication bothers me. That's why I want to go the way of the jinja2 templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would having your iptables.j2 file look something like this work?

```
# default SSH rules, etc.

{% if inventory_hostname in groups['nginx'] %}
# rules for nginx servers
{% endif %}

{% if inventory_hostname in groups['mongo'] %}
# rules for mongo servers
{% endif %}
```

Of course this would depend on your hosts being in the appropriate groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `inventory_hostname` varaible in desired `group`.
For example:

#### playbook.yml

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Custom iptables
      template: src=iptables.j2 dest="./table-{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

#### hosts

```
[all-hosts]
ansible               ansible_ssh_host=192.168.42.2
webapp                ansible_ssh_host=192.168.42.10 
postgresql            ansible_ssh_host=192.168.42.20

[ansible-host]
ansible

[webapp-hosts]
webapp

[postgresql-hosts]
postgresql
```

Then your template would look similar to this one:

#### iptables.j2

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
{% if inventory_hostname in groups['webapp-hosts'] %}
  Open 443 port
{% endif %}

{% if inventory_hostname in groups['postgresql-hosts'] %}
  Open 5432 port
{% endif %}
```

If you run the above playbook it will generate 3 files each of them will be different.